# How to split string in python using multiple delimeters

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python3 and wants to split the string into the multiple substrings. My code is shown below.

```
pr_list=re.split(r'\s{1,}', "the string, data,could have,  multiple   spaces".strip())
```

Above code works fine for single or multiple spaces which comes as a delimiter. But additionally, how can I split the same string using the another delimiter i.e. `','` as well?

For e.g.

"data,could"  string shown above also split into "data" and "could" string.

Out put i am looking is just the words, with out spaces or ','.

```
['the', 'string', 'data', 'could', 'have', 'multiple', 'spaces']
```

Comment: Change `r'\s{1,}'` to `r'[\s,]+'`. This would split things like `"hello    ,,, ,   ,,  world"` into `["hello", "world"]`, though. You didn't mention if that's a deal-breaker.

Comment: Multiple comma is not deal breaker.

Comment: Beside the point, but `x{1,}` is a more verbose way of saying `x+`

Comment: @PaulM. it worked. Please move the solution to the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this `r'[ ,]+'`

```py
import re

pr_list=re.split(r'[ ,]+', "the string, data,could have,  multiple   spaces".strip())
```

```py
>>> pr_list
['the', 'string', 'data', 'could', 'have', 'multiple', 'spaces']
```